# Learn Python The Hard Way Exercise 13 (using pycharm) - execute a script in console

Tags: python, import, terminal, console

I am obviously new to python and I've spent the last 1.5 hours beating my head against the wall trying to get this exercise done.  It should be relatively simple, and I'm sure using an IDE when I'm new is probably not doing me any favors.

Basically I have this script:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

I type the above in the editor and then I have the file saved as "ex13.py".  When I then try to run the script in the python console I am continually told that the name is not defined.  I would really appreciate any help getting this resolved, I am basically stuck and can't progress until I figure out how to run this damn script in pycharm.

Comment: Make sure you're running the python console in the same directory as the directory ex13.py is saved in.

Comment: Are you sure you need to execute this code from _python_ console? Did you meant on _terminal_ console, which is more appropriate from your `from sys import argv` command? I'm getting `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` when executing this code, which is expected, since I haven't provided any command-line arguments.

Comment: It does need to be run from terminal... yes.  As a matter of fact I was just able to get the script to execute (after providing it three arguments of course) in the Mac terminal by typing in:  python/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/untitled1/src/schoolisinsession.py   - what I'd like to do is figure out how to perform the same process within pycharm.  Run the script in the IDE without having to go do it through terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the run dropdown menu at the top of the pycharm IDE you should find edit configurations.  Click on that and write your three arguments in script paramaters.  Then run it

Answer (score 0):

in that book pointed you need pass three argument in terminal like this

```
python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
```

and if you pass more than 3 argument like what am i did, it will make you an error, like this:

```
python .\ex13.py first 2nd 3rd 4th
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\ex13.py", line 3, in <module>
    script,first,second,third= argv
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

so, pass just three argument according to that code in book, Ex13, you'll see it work